# Application hangs when I invoke join inside CyclicBarrier callback

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cyclicbarrier

I have the following method test where I start threads:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(1);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new CallbackThread(cyclicBarrier, threads));
        threads.add(thread);
        thread.start();          
    }
```

CallBack thread looks like this:

```
class CallbackThread implements Runnable {
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;
    List<Thread> threads;

    CallbackThread(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier, List<Thread> threads) {
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
        this.threads = threads;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        System.out.println("Threads started");
        for (Thread thread1 : threads) {
            try {
                thread1.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Threads finished");

    }
}
```

When I run application I see following output:

```
Threads started
```

and application hangs.

I don understand why.

If to replace join logic to main method - all goods well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(1);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new CallbackThread(cyclicBarrier, threads));
        threads.add(thread);
        thread.start();
        for (Thread thread1 : threads) {
            try {
                thread1.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Threads finished");

    }
```

Can you explain this difference.
 IMHO it should work same.

Comment: You should not add a new question but edit this question to give the correct example. I have voted to close your new question and flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: @Narendra Pathai actually I should delete this question but I cannot because it has answers

Comment: @Narendra Pathai read attentively. It is not duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from your first example calls join on its own thread. You add it to the list and the thread iterates over the list and joins every thread inside the list.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914175/application-hangs-when-i-invoke-join-inside-cyclicbarrier-callback-but-not-when

Answer (score 1):

You are joining on *self*. That's why the program never ends.

When you call the `join()` from Main thread, then main thread is trying to join the thread it created which is `CallableThread`. So it is proper.

But when you join in `CallableThread`, then you are passing `threads[]` which contains the reference to itself. So it is joining itself, which will not end.

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914175/application-hangs-when-i-invoke-join-inside-cyclicbarrier-callback-but-not-when